# How to debug server-side code in a express.js/React/Redux/gql/Apollo stack in VSC?

Tags: reactjs, express, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, react-apollo

Coming from a PHP background I am having real trouble debugging server-side code using the following set-up:

- Visual Studio Code
- Yarn
- node.js/express.js
- React
- Redux
- gql/Apollo

I start the local server with `yarn start` and then "Launch Edge against localhost" with the following launch.json...

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "url": "http://localhost:3001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have made changes to a gqp call but I am unable to get the debugger to trigger inside what I believe to be the server-side code that executes the database query located at src/data/queries/[filename].js OR after the call is made on the client side, nor do I see any error that could shed some light on what has gone wrong.

Could someone please kindly point me in the right direction for debugging in this kind of set-up? At the moment the call seems simply to fail and nothing happens.

Thank you.